# How to set controller for any route to get basic objects in all controllers

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I am building my own CMS system. And i did a lot of work with symfony in the past, now i wanna do all a bit more pro :) I want to render basic controller for admin dashboard witch contains a menu, systemnotifications on route "/admin" and then i want to set another controller for example "test" on route "/admin/test" and my problem is that all object notifications from controller named AdminController are not available in this second route "/admin/test", only on route "/admin"

Here my adminControler controller:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin", name="adminDashboard")
     */
    public function adminDashboard()
    { 

        $loggedUser = $this->getUser()->getId();

        $systemnotifications = $this->forward('App\Controller\SystemNotificationController::notif', [
        'loggedUser' => $loggedUser

        ]);
        return $this->render('admin/index.html.twig', [
                'systemnotifications' => $systemnotifications
        ]);

    }

}
```

Here my test controller:

```
class TestController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * @Route("/admin/test", name="test")
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->render('admin/dashboard/index.html.twig', [

        ]);

    }
}
```

In twig is set, that adminController extends base.html.twig, and Test controller extends index.html.twig (this one witch is rendered from adminController.

My question is how to handle it properly with Symfony best practice. How i should set the Admin Controller for get systemnotifications object where is another Test Controller launched ?

Please help :)

Comment: I need to call systemnotifications repository in each next controller ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that the first is inyect in the twig the variable. example see this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html).

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        # the value is the service's id
        user_management: '@App\DataProvider\UserDataProvider'
```

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
   'App\DataProvider\UserDataProvider':
        arguments:
            - '@session'
        autoconfigure: false
```

Comment: so if i add this as a service, how i can use it in controller, these docs are so $%^$#@

Comment: No, in the example you can inject almost any service from you service container, for example, you can pass the session service, `php bin/console debug:container` also you can inyect on any new service, remember SF4 uses autowire and Dependency Injection

Answer (score 0):

The other way is more complicate, if you for example wants the responsability to render specific part of the page, like ... the barnav or the messages

Add this piece of code to the default twig:

```
{% block user_control %}
  {{ render(controller('LayoutCoreBundle:User:index')) }}
{% endblock %}
```

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Event\ShowUserEvent;
use App\Event\ThemeEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use \stdClass;

class UserController extends EmitterController
{
    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!$this->getDispatcher()->hasListeners(ThemeEvents::THEME_NAVBAR_USER)) {
            return new Response();
        }
        /** @var ShowUserEvent $userEvent */
        $userEvent = $this->triggerMethod(ThemeEvents::THEME_NAVBAR_USER, new ShowUserEvent());
        $userClass = $userEvent->getUser();
        $user                       = new stdClass();
            $user->id               = $userClass->getIdentifier();
            $user->idEmployee       = $userClass->getIdEmployee();
            $user->setCompanyLogo   = $userClass->getCompanyLogo();
            $user->companyName      = $userClass->getCompanyName();
            $user->company          = $userClass->getCompany();
            $user->avatar           = $userClass->getAvatar();
            $user->fullName         = $userClass->getName();
            $user->menu             = $userClass->getMenu();
            $user->role             = $userClass->getRolname();
        return $this->render(
            'header/index.html.twig',
            [
                'userJson' => $user,
            ]
        );
    }

}
```

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;

class EmitterController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    protected $eventDispatcher;

    /**
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
     */
    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    /**
     * @return EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    protected function getDispatcher()
    {
        return $this->eventDispatcher;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $eventName
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function hasListener($eventName)
    {
        return $this->getDispatcher()->hasListeners($eventName);
    }

    /**
     * Will look for a method of the format "on<CamelizedEventName>" and call it with the event as argument.
     *
     *
     * Then it will dispatch the event as normal via the event dispatcher.
     *
     * @param $eventName
     * @param Event $event
     *
     * @return Event
     */
    protected function triggerMethod($eventName, Event $event)
    {
        $method = sprintf('on%s', Container::camelize(str_replace('.', '_', $eventName)));

        if (is_callable([$this, $method])) {
            call_user_func_array([$this, $method], [$event]);
        }

        if ($event->isPropagationStopped()) {
            return $event;
        }

        $this->getDispatcher()->dispatch($eventName, $event);

        return $event;
    }
}
```

```php
interface ThemeEvents
{
    /**
     * Used to receive notification data
     */
    public const THEME_NOTIFICATIONS = 'theme.notifications';
    /**
     * Used to receive message data
     */
    public const THEME_MESSAGES = 'theme.messages';
    /**
     * Used to receive task data
     */
    public const THEME_TASKS = 'theme.tasks';
    /**
     * Used to receive the current user for the navbar
     */
    public const THEME_NAVBAR_USER = 'theme.navbar_user';
    /**
     * Used to receive breadcrumb data
     */
    public const THEME_BREADCRUMB = 'theme.breadcrumb';
    /**
     * Used to receive the current user for the sidebar
     */
    public const THEME_SIDEBAR_USER = 'theme.sidebar_user';
    /**
     * Used to receive the sidebar menu data
     */
    public const THEME_SIDEBAR_SETUP_MENU = 'theme.sidebar_setup_menu';
}
```

```php
class ShowUserEvent extends ThemeEvent
{
    /**
     * @var UserInterface
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $showProfileLink = true;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $showLogoutLink = true;

    /**
     * @var NavBarUserLink[]
     */
    protected $links = [];

    /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return ShowUserEvent
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return UserInterface
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @return NavBarUserLink[]
     */
    public function getLinks()
    {
        return $this->links;
    }

    /**
     * @param NavBarUserLink $link
     * @return ShowUserEvent
     */
    public function addLink(NavBarUserLink $link)
    {
        $this->links[] = $link;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShowProfileLink()
    {
        return $this->showProfileLink;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $showProfileLink
     * @return ShowUserEvent
     */
    public function setShowProfileLink($showProfileLink)
    {
        $this->showProfileLink = $showProfileLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShowLogoutLink()
    {
        return $this->showLogoutLink;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $showLogoutLink
     * @return ShowUserEvent
     */
    public function setShowLogoutLink($showLogoutLink)
    {
        $this->showLogoutLink = $showLogoutLink;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```php
class ThemeEvent extends Event
{
}
```

And then only you need a evensuscriber

```php
class NavbarUserSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Security
     */
    protected $security;

    /**
     * @param Security $security
     */
    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            ThemeEvents::THEME_NAVBAR_USER => ['onShowUser', 100],
            ThemeEvents::THEME_SIDEBAR_USER => ['onShowUser', 100],
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @param ShowUserEvent $event
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function onShowUser(ShowUserEvent $event)
    {
        if (null === $this->security->getUser()) {
            return;
        }
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        $event->setUser($user);
    }
}
```

```
#templates/header/index.html.twig
<script type="text/javascript">
var user = {{ userJson | json_encode() | raw  }};
</script>
```

Comment: there is some "best way" or application can be coded in few ways and all can be good ? becouse i did it through to render controller in twig, and works fine, but it is good practice ? i see this events think or events by kernel, but what is the plus and minus of both solutions ? (render controller in twig and events thing) what should i use ?

Comment: for example if both works, why to do so many code in events solution?

Comment: Usually depends of your applications, complexity, maybe the conection with other apps, in code we can do it with many ways and the result will be the same, but if we based on performance when you application in young maybe the difference is in millseconds, but if you application is old or maybe complex any part of you code af you extract to be decoupling will help with the performance

Comment: Also remember, SF4, ZF3, ZF2, Laravel, all of them works in Evens to do the best performance and make the load work